# How to use a global variable as part of an array name

Tags: c++, arrays, global-variables

I have four arrays:

```
int a1 [3] = { 10, 20, 30 }; 
int a2 [3] = { 10, 20, 30 }; 
int a3 [3] = { 10, 20, 30 };
int a4 [3] = { 10, 20, 30 };
```

I want to call array depending on a global variable:

```
int sys=1;
```

lets say:

```
int a1+sys; // this should gives array a2
int a1+2*sys; // this should gives array a3
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: you can't. Why do you think you need this?

Comment: Instead of individual 1D arrays, set up a single 2D array: `int a[4][3] = { { 10, 20, 30 }, { 10, 20, 30 }, ...};` Now you can write `a[sys]`.

Comment: Maybe a 2D array: `int a[4][3] = { {10,20,23}, {....` and then `a[sys][x]` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that what you're looking for are arrays of arrays:

```
int a[][3] = {
    { 10, 20, 30 },
    { 10, 20, 30 },
    { 10, 20, 30 },
    { 10, 20, 30 },
}; 

auto& a2 = a[sys];
auto& a3 = a[2*sys];
```